# Some mails are not moved to the right inboxes

Tags: node.js, email, imap

I have an application that runs 9 mail listeners using node-imap. When a new mail arrives to one of the mails, I move it to the right box according to its title and content. The problem is that not all of the mails are moved correctly. I'll explain more after the code:

```
function sortEmails (imap, box) {
  let emails = [];
  let lead;
  let site, date;

  if (box.messages.total) {
    // fetch all of the current inbox's mails
    var imapFetch = imap.seq.fetch(`1:${box.messages.total}`, {
      bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)', 'TEXT'] // Get headers, body and struct
  });
  // For each message get the data
  imapFetch.on('message', function(msg) {
    msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
      stream.setEncoding('utf8');
      var buffer = '';
      stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
      });
      // Once done, check if lead or not, and act accordingly.
      stream.once('end', function() {
        // If header
        if (info.which !== 'TEXT') {
          let header = Imap.parseHeader(buffer);
          // If lead, set date & site of lead.
          if (header.subject[0] === 'Lead') {
            site = header.from[0].slice(header.from[0].indexOf("@") + 1, -1);
            date = header.date[0];
          };
        // If body
        } else {
            // if lead (spam leads included) and not regular mail.
            if (site && date) {
              body = parseMailBody(buffer);
              // Create a new lead
              lead = new Lead(body.name, body.email, body.phone, date, site, body.url, body.ip);
              if (lead.isRealLead()) {
                emails.push(lead);
              } else {
                lead = 'spam';
              }
            }
          }
      });
  });
    msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
      if (!lead) {
        imap.move(attrs.uid, imap.boxes.all, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            logger.log('error', 'Mail Listeners', 'Move error: ' + err);
          }         
        });
      } else if (lead === 'spam') {
          imap.move(attrs.uid, imap.boxes.spamLeads, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              logger.log('error', 'Mail Listeners', 'Move error: ' + err);
            }
          }); 
        } else {
          imap.move(attrs.uid, imap.boxes.leads, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              logger.log('error', 'Mail Listeners', 'Move error: ' + err);
            }
          });
        }
    });
  });
  imapFetch.once('error', function(err) {
    logger.log('error', 'Mail Listeners', 'Fetch error: ' + err);
  });

  imapFetch.once('end', function() {
    if (emails.length !== 0) {
      sendBotMessage(`A new lead has just arrived.`);
      sendToDB(emails);
    }
  });
  }
}
```

Basically, if a mail **doesn't have the title 'Lead' it will be moved to the 'ALL' directory**. In addition, mails that do have the 'Lead' title and contain only English chars will be marked as spam.

The problem is, some of the mails which **are leads** (contain the 'Lead' title and names are not in english) are moved to the **'ALL'** folder, indicating the (!lead) is true.

The mails are received from a CF7 form in Wordpress. This is a MIME of a mail that wasn't moved correctly:

```
Return-Path: <my@host.co.il>
Delivered-To: my@mail.co.il
Received: from s-inbox.upress.io
    by s-inbox.upress.io with LMTP
    id OKTqFcSEIFzwBwAAmWbRAw
    (envelope-from <my@host.co.il>)
    for <my@mail.co.il>; Mon, 24 Dec 2018 09:03:32 +0200
Return-path: <my@host.co.il>
Envelope-to: my@mail.co.il
Delivery-date: Mon, 24 Dec 2018 09:03:32 +0200
Received: from my@host.co.il ([myip])
    by s-inbox.upress.io with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.90_1)
    (envelope-from <my@host.co.il>)
    id 1gbKGy-0000tR-6i
    for my@mail.co.il; Mon, 24 Dec 2018 09:03:32 +0200
Received: from hostname by my@host.co.il with local (Exim 4.87)
    (envelope-from <my@host.co.il>)
    id 1gbKGw-0000Lk-Oz
    for my@mail.co.il; Mon, 24 Dec 2018 09:03:30 +0200
To: my@mail.co.il
Subject: Lead
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1029:class-phpmailer.php
Date: Mon, 24 Dec 2018 07:03:30 +0000
From: WordPress <admin@domain.co.il>
Reply-To: test@gmail.com
Message-ID: <7b2769f42336ec7bf49edce68de30074@domain.co.il>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Sender:  <my@host.co.il>
SPFCheck: Server passes SPF test, -30 Spam score
Forward-Confirmed-ReverseDNS: Reverse and forward lookup success on 185.217.97.242, -10 Spam score
SpamTally: Final spam score: -40

name: בדיקה
mail: test@gmail.com
phone: 0435599539
ip: 84.108.61.243
url: https://myurl.co.il/
```

I am kind of new to the concept of streams in general and imap in particular, and I can't seem to figure out what's the problem here.

Thank you for your reading time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with node but it looks like you have hard-coded some assumptions about MIME structure and message encoding which may not hold for all messages. What is the MIME type of the failed messages and are they encoded as you expect?

Comment: Can you please point me to the part of the code you're talking about? Some part of the code is taken from the [node imap package page](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap). Also, how can I check the MIME type of the failed messages? @tripleee

Comment: Including the source of one of the messages would perhaps be helpful, though if they are bulky, reduce it to just the headers and some placeholder text. I'm looking at the utf-8 assumption in particular. I'm not sure what sort of normalization `parseMailBody` does but if you feed it incorrectly decoded data, I imagine you could easily end up with garbage output.

Comment: I added the source of the emails and `parseMailBody` so you can have a look :) @tripleee

Comment: That's not email source, those are some random contents from one body part. The MIME structure looks something like this (random find from Pastebin by googling): https://pastebin.com/0CZ5iqyG

Comment: Alright, I'm trying to find it without any luck. Is is supposed to be on my server config or is it configured in the wordpress plugin?

Comment: It is the actual email. If you visit the IMAP inbox using a regular email client and view the source of a message, that's what you'll see.

Comment: Added the MIME now @tripleee

Comment: Thanks. The UTF-8 assumption seems correct for this individual message; was it incorrectly filed? Also, sending UTF-8 text/plain as Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit is slightly unconventional.

Comment: Yes, this message was incorrectly moved to the 'ALL' directory. Also, I have no idea what to do with the information you just gave me :) How can I change the encoding? I don't even recall setting it

Comment: The sending PHP script is responsible for how the message is formatted. Can you show the source of a message which was not correctly filed instead, or as well?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean by not correctly filled. The message I posted should have gone to the Leads folder and it went to the 'ALL' folder, so it didn't work as expected. Do you mean you want to see a mail that should be tagged as spam?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your earlier comment -- nvm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186098/discussion-between-tripleee-and-sagi-rika).